# Do i need to broadcast a dataframe in spark SQL every iteration?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL to do join for iterations with a loop-invariant dataframe. I am wondering if I need to broadcast it in every iteration or I just broadcast it in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if the dataframe is little enough, spark broadcast it without that you have to do

```
  Import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.broadcast

   bigDF       
   .join(broadcast(smalldf), Seq("field"), "left_outer")
```

Ok, I understand, then you have to broadcast every loop, because new df arrives at workers and you it'll cleaned once finished.

Comment: I want to maintain the same DF in the memory until the program ends.

Comment: No matter the df joined with CachedDF is smaller or bigger than it, I want to maintain the same CachedDF in memory.